# Why get I a NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error in virtualbox guest system when i use a vpn on the host system?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, windows, vpn

When im brwosing on my virtualbox guest system (Win 10), im getting a NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error.
On my host system (Ubuntu) everything works fine.

As network setting i configured NAT.

I use Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and our company VPN (openVPN). The Virtualbox version is 6.1.16_Ubuntu r140961

Comment: What Ubuntu version? What VPN?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and our company VPN (openVPN). The Virtualbox version s 6.1.16_Ubuntu r140961

Comment: How did you solved this problem ? I am using same Ubuntu version in VMware workstation 16

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by adding a bridged network and disabling the NAT adapter from the network settings of vbox. I dont know what exactly is the trouble that these HTTPS sites see when the VM is reaching the network through a NATTed tunnel via the host OS

Comment: For bridged network do I need to connect to VPN from VM as well ? Or host is fine ? If I am bridged network I am getting Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED